# PySpark dataframe drops records while writing to a hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe to hive table which also got created using the below line

```
 parks_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("fs.PARKS_TNTO")
```

When I try to print the count of the dataframe `parks_df.count()` I get 1000 records.

But in the final table `fs.PARKS_TNTO`, I get 980 records. Hence 20 records are getting dropped. How can I resolve this issue ? . Also , how can I capture the records which are getting dropped. There are no partitions on this final table `fs.PARKS_TNTO`.

Comment: Could it be a result of datatype mismatch or rows with nulls got dropped when inserting into a non-nullable field? Maybe compare the dataframe structure `parks_df.printSchema()` with the table structure of `PARKS_TNTO` (`desc PARKS_TNTO`).  Also, you can read the table `PARKS_TNTO` info a dataframe and outer join on `parks_df` to see which records are dropped.

Comment: But this table gets created directly from the dataframe when i use the "overwrite" option.

Comment: Yeah I understand you use `overwrite` into a new table, however, the HIVE table schema is inferred, that's why I suggest to cross-check the schema from both sides.

Comment: I see that in the dataframe few columns are of type "long" whereas in the hive table, they are mapped to "BIGINT"